# html slideshow in div background image

Tags: html, slideshow

Good day to all. I am new and novice and its my first question to this forum. I would try my level best to maintain dignity of this community and forum.

I just started to learn web development with html, css and java script. I was trying to make a slide show of images with "div" and backgroup-images. after lots of effort it worked but not smooth.

Images not appears one by one serial but skip randomly. Speed of slides are not uniform and after few seconds it goes very fast.

I was using "setInterval" in my codes.

```
<!-- scroll.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name= "index.html" content="html self made web site "> 
    <meta name= "keywords" content="web design, affordable and professional">
    <meta name="description" content="Affordable and smart web desing without any builders rather via self made codes">
    <meta name="Author" content="Binod Binani">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0">
    <!--Css link -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../HTML-WEB/sc-css/sc_style1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../html-web/java-js/slides.js" ></script>  -->
    <title>#Sharp Compusoft scroll#</title>
    <style>
       #Myimg{

       } 
       #divBox{
         min-height: 425px; 
         border: 2px black solid;
         float: right ;width: 48%;

         background-image: url("../html-web/sharp-slides/05.bmp");
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         padding: auto;
       }  
       #divSlides{
          background-image: url("../HTML-WEB/img/it-slide01.jpg");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
          min-height: 425px; 
          border: 2px blue solid;float: 
          left; width: 50%;
       }  
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="showImages()">
    <section id='Middle' style="max-height: 430px;margin-top: 100px; border: 8px yellow solid; position: relative;">
        <div id="divMiddle" style="min-height:425px; border: 5px red solid; margin: auto;">
            <div id="divSlides" >       
                <!--50% left for fix image"> -->
            </div>
            <div id='divBox'>  
                    <!--50% right for sliding image. Images are from 1 to 12 slides"> -->
               <h4 id='head4'>1/12</h4> 
            </div> 

        </div>          
    </section>

<script>
    var imageNo=1;
    var extension='.bmp")';
    var filepath='url("../HTML-WEB/sharp-slides/'

    showImages();

    function showImages(){

        var ImageSource=""

        if (imageNo > 12)  {
            imageNo=1 ;
        }
        if (imageNo< 10){
            ImageSource= filepath +"0" +imageNo + extension ;

         } else{
            ImageSource= filepath +imageNo + extension  
         }
        head4.innerHTML = imageNo+'/12'
        document.getElementById('divBox').style.backgroundImage = ImageSource;
        imageNo++; //increment by 1 step
        setTimeout(showImages,5000);
    } // showImages

</script> -->   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of things causing the issue you are describing

First, you are calling `showImages()` three times, all they are all running at the same time, causing the timeouts to overlap and the image to jump out of order.

You should remove this function call `<body onload="showImages()">`

And this one too `setTimeout(showImages,5000);`

Then use `setInterval`, instead of `setTimeout`, the difference is that the interval keeps running every given time, instead of running just once like the timeout.

Here change `showImages();` to `var slidesInteval = setInterval(showImages,5000);`

```
var imageNo=1;
var extension='.bmp")';
var filepath='url("../HTML-WEB/sharp-slides/'

var slidesInteval = setInterval(showImages,5000);
```

That way you function will be running only once every 5 seconds, you need to store the interval in a variable in case you want to clear it later.

You can check the full fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/zgranda/5gnfr7hv/8/ . I used lorem picsum for the images, so don't copy the images urls